# In Ramayana, how was Nala able to build the Rama Setu?

Tags: ramayana, vanaras, ram-setu

As per normal human thinking it is impossible to build a bridge on sea.

Then how could Nala, a mere vanara, build the Rama Setu across the sea?

Comment: You can find the details in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3122/1018)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ramayana, almost all Vanaras are the incarnation or Ansha of some deity and so was the Nala. Nala was the son of Vishvakarma (the divine architect) and he had a boon of his father. It is described in [Yuddha Kand, Chapter 22](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga22/yuddha_22_frame.htm) as:

> अयम् सौम्य नलो नाम तनुजो विश्व कर्मणः |
>   पित्रा दत्त वरः श्रीमान् प्रतिमो विश्व कर्मणः || २-२२-४४
>
> O, excellent man! This one, named Nala, a glorious person, is the son of Vishvakarma; who was given a boon by his father and is equal to Visvakarma.
>
> एष सेतुम् महाउत्साहः करोतु मयि वानरः |
>   तम् अहम् धारयिष्यामि तथा हि एष यथा पिता || २-२२-४५
>
> Let this greatly energetic monkey build a bridge across me. I can hold that bridge. He is just the same as his father.