# Is there any scientific or historical evidence that Ramayana is true?

Tags: ramayana, history

I wanted to know whether there is any scientific or historical proof that the stories and events mentioned in Ramayana are true or is everything just a made-up story?

Comment: I don't know whether you would get any proof because it happened some 1 billion years ago.

Comment: But you can find the social proof of Ramayana in that even today it exists. Even today people are inspired by it.

Comment: @Surya How about Ram Setu ? And all the stones that float on water if you write **Ram** on it in hindi ofcourse :P If this is not possible how can I believe in hinduism ?

Comment: Of course Rama Setu is one big evidence; but frankly speaking you need not have any evidence at all and Rama will still inspire you. That is prof enough. But still wait for others to answer.

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/379/2995) for on-topic questions. Questions seeking scientific proof or speculation are not allowed here.

Comment: There's already a question on Rama Sethu: [What does the Ramayana say about floating stones of Ram Sethu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/217/2995)

Comment: @Surya  Ramayana actually happened in 24th Treta yuga. Currently we are in 28th Kaliyuga. So roughly it was around 1,81,44,000 (1.8 crores or 18 million years ago)

Comment: Yes, there is proof of Ramayana as I discuss [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9015/3872).

Comment: Swami Vivekananda says that it doesn't matter whether you accept it as historically true or not, what is important are the lessons we learn from it.

Comment: @sv. The rule against scientific speculation is about when people baselessly speculate that some Hindu practice or belief is actually based on something in modern science. Like "When Krishna says ... in the Bhagavad Gita, he's referring to the Theory of Relativity" or "The reason Hindus do namaskaram is because it absorbs the Earth's magnetic field."  That's the sort of thing that's not allowed.  But saying "archeologists have found this evidence of this event in the Ramayana" would be fine.

Comment: Yes ShriRama Himself is the evidence that Ramayana is True. Lord Rama is present in your Heart (Ayodhya). Your Mind (Sita) is asking God for Worldly objects (Deer) and thus in pursuit of it, Your Mind is taken by Your Ten Senses (Dashamukha Ravana). Lord Rama (God) is now seeking to regain Sita along with Intellect (Lakshmana), Courage (Anjaneya) and His Vanara Army. This is called Sadhana. By doing Sadhana, one gets the 100% direct proof of Lord Rama. No other proof (Rama sethu, siddhis, etc.) can convince anyone other than direct proof. All the best. Thanks sir

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan IMHO, scientific proof makes sense for questions like _Did dinosaurs really exist?_ which has nothing to do with religion, beliefs and culture. To such a question one can simply answer by saying, yes, the proof is in the dinosaur fossils uncovered at so & so place and on display in so & so museums. There is and there cannot be any scientific proof for 99.99% of answers on Hinduism.SE.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Clearly, OP's objective in the question is that lacking _scientific proof_, Ramayana has to be a made-up story. Couple of comments above claim to have 'proofs' of Ramayana but they are not really 'scientific' proofs as those answers are based on scriptures. And scriptures themselves cannot be proof of what's written in them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something I posted a while back in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-ramayana-is-not-a-myth/answer/Vineet-Menon-1)

Veracity of a story is often affirmed through certain evidences mainly,

1. Literary; i.e. if the same incident is mentioned repeatedly in many stories by various sources, there *could* be some truth to it.
2. Geographical/Geological; If the places and other landmarks really exist(ed). It again gives more credibility to the story.
3. Archaeological; This is the most important source of evidence, which unfortunately rarely provides any in case of myths about humans, because of the devastating effect nature has on human artifacts and creations.
4. Astronomical; More potent source of evidence, but with less credibility than archaeological one. The dates and position of celestial bodies in heaven as described in the texts when verified with latest planetary charts can validate the authenticity of the myths.

Ramayana conforms excellently on Literary, Geographical and Astronomical fronts.

[image]

Magenta line is the path Rama traveled from Ayodhya to Lanka for Sita during his *Vanavaas*.
The sites like Rameshwaram, Ayodhya, Hastinapur, Kaushal, Mithila, panchavati, Dandakaranya etc. are still in use in modern day India (except Dandakaranya forest, which was later subjected to deforestation for human settlement).

Astronomical -

1. [The Scientific Dating Ramayana and the Vedas - P V Vartak](http://www.scribd.com/doc/23133909/The-Scientific-Dating-Ramayana-and-the-Vedas-P-V-Vartak#scribd)
2. [The problem of using Astronomy in dating the Vedas, Ramayana, Mahabharata](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/The_problem_of_using_Astronomy_in_dating_the_Vedas,_Ramayana,_Mahabharata)

Now one can always counter all these arguments saying that

1. A person well versed in the geography of India could have simply connected various places in India to craftily concoct a story around them.
2. Since, ancient Indian astronomers were experts in their field, they could have easily back calculated the planetary position, and used it in the stories.

I don't have a response to these questions, which begs me to ask about the reason for asking the authenticity of these stories. Does a Hindu need these stories to be true for affirming his belief in Hinduism (Sanatana Dharma)? Does his faith requires Ramayana and Mahabharata to be true to the word? If yes, which version of it? A. K. Ramanujam's 'The 300 Ramayanas' details the myriad variations in the retelling of this one epic in entire South Asia and South East Asia including Indonesia, Malaysia, Java and Sumatra.

Hinduism, unlike Abrahamic religions aren't History centric (I'm using the same terminology as used by Mr. Rajiv Malhotra). Even if Ramayana and Mahabharata were classic representation of archetypes instead of real man in blood and bones, it would do no harm to any Hindu, unlike a Muslim for whom the existence of Mohammed is as mandatory as to a Jesus is to a Christian.

Comment: given enough time, people will start doubting their own life. it's 2000 years and people are doubting whether jesus existed. In another 200 years, people will doubt whether hitler existed.

Comment: tbh, there are no archaeological evidence whether Jesus existed or not. Even the liturgical evidence is heavily redacted by various papal commissions.

Comment: well of course, jesus was not a dinosaur, or an architect of large cities, so we're not going to find fossils or stonehenges. anyone insisting on archaeological evidence is like asking for a particular spec of dust after a sandstorm.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to me loaded, in the sense that, you wish to juxtapose Science and Religion and want to see one in the light of the other. Hinduism is a religion, it's driven by faith, even if not supported by facts and events as we capture them with our senses, but sense their presence and relevance, because of their impact on the way of life. That's the basis of all religions, not just Hinduism.

Whether you are looking a scientific validation of epic events or you are looking to undermine them by holding them against a scientific mirror, the question may not be valid in this forum because it's likely to produce opinion-based discussions.

Nevertheless, here is an answer that will be honey to your ears :

**No.**

As scientific and historic studies stand today, there is no irrefutable, conclusive evidence in the scientific, archaeological excavation and historic dates sense about the events in the Ramayana, outside of the calculations and chronological backdating from the framework of Hinduism itself.

However, cultural impact and continuity is considered an integral part in validating and endorsing historic prevalences and other fields related to history, such as [cultural anthropology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_anthropology). In that sense, even if it's a story today, there is still scope for future evidence to meet and validate the events.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_studies

Comment: First of all, this question is off-topic for this site. please don't answer such questions and flag/vote to close the question. Thanks.

Comment: Disagree that this question is off-topic.Noticed the question was downvoted, yet I answered it. These are some most frequently asked questions about hinduism, among youth when they are coming to terms with religion in a modern world. A willingness to answer these questions, will help them to embrace and explore Hinduism better. If there is a list of "what is on-topic" elsewhere, and if such questions are not in that definition, consider this comment as my representation to the community to add "helps engage Hinduism" as a criterion.