# Is ramayana a history or an entertainment?

Tags: ramayana, valmiki

I believe in God. I fully support scriptures & their ideals. I came across many hindus (including educated persons) & saw that most of hindus believe in Ramayana. Please know the views of some qualified experts [here](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Was-saner-advice-on-Setu-affidavit-ignored/articleshow/2367069.cms):

However, some or a few of them say that it is just an entertainment or fiction written by sage/poet Valmiki who exaggerated & inflated many things to make it interesting such as Lord Rama was God, he had supernatural power to do many abnormal things which a human can't. Can someone provide me some proof or any line in Ramayana that says that it a real history not a fiction?

One thing I want to know:

- Is there any descriptions or a single line in Valmiki's Ramayana which ensures that Ramayana was a history not an entertainment.

  Jai Sri Ram!

Comment: See [Is there any evidence that Ramayana is true?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9642/3500)

Comment: See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/why-are-only-ramayana-and-mahabharata-classified-as-itihasa/11830#11830). Ramayana was not an entertainment.

Comment: "Can someone provide me some proof or any line in Ramayana that says that it a real history not a fiction?" - can you prove you are a real person and not a robot :) If someone reads your autobiography a 1000 years from now, how to prove your 'biography' is 'real' and not 'fiction'? Two more biographies from the same time each validating the other is good enough as 'proof' for some but for others it still won't suffice. For some, Ramayana is just a good story teaching human values, for some every word of it is history. So ultimately it's a matter of your personal belief.

Comment: Why does it matter? It is an epic poem that has taught millions of people how to live righteously who do not have the time or inclination to study the formal scriptures.