# About the Ram setu bridge on a floating stones

Tags: ramayana

Floating stones are used to build this bridge `Ram Setu` but now the NASA found it is under the sea however the floating stones how could sink in the ocean.

**Updated:** Its actually the story of war within Rama and Ravana by the way Rama and his army entering via floating bridge build by Nala. All the things are clear and understood.

Now the `Floating stones` why `sunk` in an ocean now.

Comment: @dr.vineetaggarwal Can you please tell me where you mentioned post is answering the OP's question? Which line of you linked post is answering his question? Besides he is also asking different thing than your linked post.

Comment: Oops my mistake i was actually referring to this post - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/217/what-does-the-ramayana-say-about-floating-stones-of-ram-sethu

Comment: I have udpated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Ramayana say about floating stones of Ram Sethu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/217/5212). About floating stones, it is already asked. If you are asking why they were sunk, it is scientific speculation. It is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Its not going to off-topic or duplicate answer. I accepted the @YDS answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sources (mostly Puranas) which talk about floating stones don't refer to the latest Ramayana. They tell about some other Kalpa's Ramayana.

Please see Tulsidas's explanation in Ramcharitmanas 1.33 (for more details, please see  this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304)):

> नाना भाँति राम अवतारा। रामायन सत कोटि अपारा।।
>
> **कलपभेद** हरिचरित सुहाए। भाँति अनेक मुनीसन्ह गाए।।

In the latest Ramayana, the bridge was not built with stones only but trees, rocks and mountains ([Yuddha Kanda - Sarga 22](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga22/yuddha_22_frame.htm)).

The floating stones theory doesn't seems 100% true in the current Kalpa rather it seems the great work of an Engineer/Architect.

Nala was son of Vishvakarnma (the great Architect of Devas) and got to know the art from his father. [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22917/12304) is what Nala himself says in Valmiki Ramayana.

And a bridge made by an Engineer/Architect may collapse, at least after thousands of thousands years.

Comment: Does that mean ramayana is repeated many times per kalpa?

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 No...only once per kalpa..there hv been many kalpa (360*50+) in current Brahma's lifespan... However few people say Ramayana gets repeated in every manvantara or mahayuga if that's true u can say many times in one kalpa but there r not strong proofs for this...